# Bootstrap grid with unequal col numbers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a grid using bootstrap 3, to create something like this:
[image]

I'm using box to create the squares, and the box is used like a link. 
This should be used as a custom made navigation bar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13320/

Using the 12 column grid, i made the two outer buttons small by giving them the `1` value and the middle a `10` then the `divs` inside the `10` column I gave them each a `4` 3x4 = 12 and in boostrap that is 100% of the parent.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border-style: solid; border-color: blue;">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
             <h3 style="border-style: solid; border-color: red;"><</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
             <h3 style="border-style: solid; border-color: green;">X</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
             <h3 style="border-style: solid; border-color: green;">X</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
             <h3 style="border-style: solid; border-color: green;">X</h3>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
             <h3 style="border-style: solid; border-color: red;">></h3> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AHJ can you mark this as correct if this is all you needed? That way others don't come to your question thinking it still needs to be answered.